# Intune MAM SDK: get managed application list?

Tags: android, intune

I am using Intune SDK in my Android application.

I am trying to get managedPackageList (target apps added in intune app protectin at azure portal).

```
AppPolicy appPolicy = MAMPolicyManager.getPolicy();
String policy = appPolicy.toString();
```

There is no method in `appPolicy` to get managed package list but `policy` (appPolicy.toString()) contains managedPackageList and many other policy information.

If anyone can help to get a list of the managed package as Java list or array. I dont want to do the dirty work of extracting the list from `policy`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The list of managed applications is not exposed through the Intune SDK, and it is not expected that apps will need it. Could you elaborate on why this information is required -- i.e. what is the root problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Electron I want to show the list of intune applications that can handle a given file, but Instead of showing all installed applications which can handle that file I want to show a list of application enabled from policy at the azure portal and can handle the file.

Comment: If you simply try to send an intent as you normally would, the Intune SDK will intercept that and display a chooser dialog showing only managed application. If you need to show your own chooser UI for some reason, you can use `PackageManager.queryIntentActivities` which will also be intercepted.

Comment: @Electron Do we need to do something to make intune intercept the intent because I am creating my chooser UI and using PackageManager.queryIntentActivities but don't see any filtering. I am Using ApplicationContext to initialize PackageManager . Can you guide me into that?

Comment: @Electron I have tried with chooser intent. Yes, when we fire chooser intent Intune intercepts and only show only managed applications. Science I need my own chooser UI, I have tried with PackageManager.queryIntentActivities but it is not intercepted and gives the list of all installed applications. 

Is there any other way you can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The Intune App SDK consists of the following files:

**Microsoft.Intune.MAM.SDK.aar**: The SDK components, with the exception of the Support Library JAR files.

**Microsoft.Intune.MAM.SDK.Support.v4.jar**: The classes necessary to enable MAM in apps that use the Android v4 support library.

**Microsoft.Intune.MAM.SDK.Support.v7.jar:** The classes necessary to enable MAM in apps that use the Android v7 support library.

**Microsoft.Intune.MAM.SDK.Support.v17.jar:** The classes necessary to enable MAM in apps that use the Android v17 support library.

**Microsoft.Intune.MAM.SDK.Support.Text.jar**: The classes necessary to enable MAM in apps that use Android support library classes in the android.support.text package.

**Microsoft.Intune.MDM.SDK.DownlevelStubs.jar**: This jar contains stubs for Android system classes which are present only on newer devices but which are referenced by methods in MAMActivity. Newer devices will ignore these stub classes. This jar is necessary only if your app performs reflection on classes deriving from MAMActivity, and most apps do not need to include it. If you use this jar, you must be careful to exclude all its classes from ProGuard. They will all be under the "android" root package

**com.microsoft.intune.mam.build.jar:** A Gradle plugin which aids in integrating the SDK.

**CHANGELOG.txt:** Provides a record of changes made in each SDK version.

**THIRDPARTYNOTICES.TXT:** An attribution notice that acknowledges third-party and/or OSS code that will be compiled into your app.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-sdk-android#whats-in-the-sdk

Comment: I think you haven't read the question. Your answer is just a copy past from intune docs. I don't think you should post the answer if you haven't understood the problem. If you have any query, we could discuss in the comments. Please take care because this answer is neither relevant nor useful.